# How to validate embedded signatures in PDFs on Android?

Tags: android, security, pdf, certificate

I'm searching for a library that is able to validate embedded signatures in PDFs on Android. Does anyone know a library fulfiling the following requirements:

1. validating whether the signed document was changed or not
2. validating whether the certificate was manipulated
3. validating that the certificate isn't expired
4. resolve the certification chain to a trusted entity

I have tested the following ones and they don't meet the requirements:

- [Apache PDFbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)
- [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/)
- [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/)

I'm aware that the [Qoppa qPDF Toolkit](https://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/) is able to solve our issues, but I don't have the required resources to obtain a license.

Interesting side fact: I haven't even found a PDFreader app which seems to be able to show this information. If someone knows an app which provides this functionality, this information would be very much appreciated too.

Comment: *I have tested the following ones:* - and what was the result?

Comment: Sorry...the result is that they don't support the listed requirements.

Comment: In which way? I don't know about PDFjet, but the former two libraries definitively allow you to extract the CMS signature container to do any validation you want using e.g. BouncyCastle/SpongyCastle. And iText offers a number of validation tests out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You could check [DSS](https://github.com/esig/dss), it includes a validation component, you can test it from the [frontend web demo](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/sd-dss/webapp-demo/validation). It uses PDFBox features and includes its own for validation. This is an European Commision endorsed project, so it features existing PAdES level profiles validation, apart of non-PAdES, customizable validation policies and built-in trusted validation lists.